# How to import binary arcgis maps into R

Tags: raster, r

I have imported arcgis rasters into R.  The rasters are binary maps and the legend in arcgis shows this to be binary as the colors are only 0 and 1.  Now, when I import the raster into R it is no longer binary, as there are 5 numbers in the legend.  Does anyone know why this occurred and have a solution to fix this?

My other question is, when I load a raster in arcgis, how do I effectively change the legend and then save the raster as a different name?

This is m R code for importing the raster and then making a 4 paneled plot.  I have no idea how to change the legend in R.

```
r5<-raster("C:/users/k/desktop/g/A1b00-59/dican00")
r6<-raster("C:/users/k/desktop/g/A1b50-59/dican50")
r7<-raster("C:/users/k/desktop/g/A1b50-59/dican59")
r8<-raster("C:/users/k/desktop/g/A1b00-59/dicancalc")


par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(r5,sub="2000 Distribution",col.sub="blue")
points(Dican,col='blue')
title(main="A1b scenario Panic Grass Distributions",col.main="red")
plot(r6,sub="2050 Distribution",col.sub="blue")
points(Dican,col='blue')
plot(r7,sub="2059 Distribution",col.sub="blue")
points(Dican,col='blue')
plot(r8,sub="Net Habitat Change Panic Grass",col.sub="blue")
points(Dican,col='blue')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't trust legends! What does a tabulation of the imported raster values tell you? (Use `freq` as in `freq(r5)`.) If there are indeed additional values beyond {0,1}, exactly what are they and how often do they occur?  To change the legend, consult the manual page for `plot {raster}`; it has many examples.